# Where to get Android SDK 20 AVD? Is it not in support anymore?

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

As shown in the AVD Manager below, we only have SDK 16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23 and 24 AVD. Where could I get SDK 20?

[image: AVD Manager]

I just want to use it to test an Android issue, and verify on which version that issue is fixed. It happens on v19 and not on v21. So I want to confirm if v20 also have the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Version `20` was a temporary SDK version for the Android Wear preview version labeled as `KitKat-watch`.

Hence, it's not available anymore, and there should not be any devices "out there" running it.

Comment: Thanks! This helps much!